# Prevent excel updating cell referene with new location

Tags: excel, reference, formula

this should be super basic but I can't figure it out.

If I have a series of numbers in A1:A10. And in B1 i have [=A1], B2 [=A2] etc. Simple cell reference.

My problem is that when I select A1:A10 and move them down to A2:A11, the formulas in column B update to reflect the new location. What I want is the reference to be permanently on A1:A10.

I've tied =$A$1, but that too updates to $A$2 when I shift the cells.

How do I break the lock on the values?

Comment: In B1, you could use offset of itself instead of =A1 so instead use `=OFFSET(B1,0,-1)` where -1 is saying look one cell to the left of me

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to achieve this using the `INDIRECT` formula, like this:

```
B1: =INDIRECT("A1")
B2: =INDIRECT("A2")
...
```

The references are not updated because they are strings.